# SQL Developer : Unable to gather system statistics : insufficient privileges

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-grant

I was trying to gather system statistics to get the report information.
I tried the same via `SQL developer` and found some privillage issues and I referred this [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/653571?start=0&tstart=0) for the solution,

```
GRANT CREATE session TO TEST_DB;
GRANT GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS TO TEST_DB; 
GRANT CONNECT TO TEST_DB;
```

All grant succeeded.But,

```
execute dbms_stats.gather_system_stats ('START');
```

gave me the error

```
ORA-20000: Unable to gather system statistics : insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 23190
```

Finally, I tried with command line and finished the things without any issues,

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

why it was showing insufficient privileges issue in `SQL developer` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role privileges like `GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS` (as opposed to sys privileges, like `CREATE TABLE`) don't take effect immediately; they only take effect at the next logon (presumably because Oracle does some kind of caching internally).

So if you'd logged off and on in SQL Developer, it would have worked, as well.