# How to collect more statistics in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-execution-plan

I'm new to Oracle and would like to know the way how to get more statistics in the case i'll describe below. I'm using SQL Developer.

First, I execute this:

```
SET autotrace on;

SELECT NAME
FROM PASSENGER
WHERE ID_PSG IN (
    SELECT ID_PSG
    FROM PASS_IN_TRIP PIT JOIN TRIP T on T.TRIP_NO = PIT.TRIP_NO
    WHERE UPPER(TOWN_FROM) = 'MOSCOW'
    )
```

In Script Output I can see info about the query from PLAN_TABLE table and after that there's the text:

> Unable to gather statistics please ensure user has correct access. The
> statistic feature requires that the user is granted select on
> v_$sesstat, v_$statname and v_$session.

I've tried to find a solution here already, there's a link:
[SQL Developer : Unable to gather system statistics : insufficient privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822526/sql-developer-unable-to-gather-system-statistics-insufficient-privileges)
So I executed the same commands and the grants were all succeded:

```
GRANT CREATE session TO PRACTICE;
GRANT GATHER_SYSTEM_STATISTICS TO PRACTICE; 
GRANT CONNECT TO PRACTICE;
```

Then I disconnected, closed SQL dev, opened it, connected again as it was described in the solution from the link, ran

```
execute dbms_stats.gather_system_stats ('START');
```

and got this:

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Then I thought everything is fine and tried to execute the code from the very beginning and its Script Output was still the same as before.
Do I have to grant anything else or this statistics can be found in the other place or I just did everything wrong?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what privileges you are missing: "select on v_$sesstat, v_$statname and v_$session". The question is not about "collecting more statistics"; it's about accessing those already collected.

Comment: login as an admin or get a dba to grant select on v$... to PRACTICE;

Comment: Thank you for giving the right direction! Everything works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is about `sqlplus autotrace`, it's not about gathering system statistics like your linked post seems to be about.

There is a role created specifically for these grants called `plustrace` https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_eight.htm#SQPUG535

> To use this feature, you must create a PLAN_TABLE table in your schema
> and then have the PLUSTRACE role granted to you. DBA privileges are
> required to grant the PLUSTRACE role. For information on how to grant
> a role and how to create the PLAN_TABLE table, see the Oracle Database
> SQL Language Reference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just created PLAN_TABLE in my schema sucessfully, created plustrace and gave it to my user with admin option. But still, when I execute the first query it replies with the same message as before. Maybe I have to execute another code to get there stats not that I tried before?

Comment: well, it workes fine from user with SYSDBA role, maybe I forgot to grant something, thank you for your answer again!

Comment: Roles have to be set - this will happen automatically on connection most of the time but if you were trying to use the privileges in an already connected session you have to use the `set role .. ` syntax